# Rails 3 routing - :delete method on :collection

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, routes

I want to create a route to allow deleting all `shares`. RESTful way would be to use verb `DELETE`. How can I create a routing that points to:

```
DELETE /shares
```

I tried in the routes:

```
resources :shares do
  delete :on => :collection
end
```

But this yielded an error that rails can't turn `nil` into a symbol.

For now I have:

```
resources :shares do
  delete 'delete_all', :on => :collection
end
```

**EDIT:** I had a typo in controller action name and this latter way works, but produces URL `/shares/delete_all` which is not very RESTful.

How can I drop the _delete_all_ part?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> What am I missing?

```
match 'shares', :to => 'shares#delete_all', :via => :delete
```

more info: http://www.engineyard.com/blog/2010/the-lowdown-on-routes-in-rails-3/

`<subjective opinion>`
This is generally a bad idea and a code/design smell. The need to be deleting all records via a RESTful interface should really be behind a protected (authenticated) action and/or the action should be scoped to the user somehow.

Comment: There is nothing in his question or your answer that necessitate that the delete method for all shares does not require authentication, or could not require authorization. You can never tell just from the routes whether or not an action checks proper authorization before actually doing what you're asking it to do.

Comment: Hence why I was trying to give him the heads up to save frustration in the future.

Comment: Of course this worked! I somehow was thinking inside the `resource` box and forgot all about `match`. BTW, we _are_ using proper authorization and this is for development anyway and probably will be removed from production when ready.

Comment: Yeah, sorry  if my `subjective opinion` seemed to harsh. For dev purposes, its a find little action, in the wild-- don the fireproof gloves :)

Answer (score 15):

For Rails 3 you can do it this way and have nice resourceful GET/DELETE collection actions pointing to index and delete_all respectively:

```
resources :shares do
  delete :index, on: :collection, action: :delete_all
end
```

If you're using Rails 4 you can make use of concerns to DRY this up and apply it to many resources:

```
concern :deleteallable do
  delete :index, on: :collection, action: :delete_all
end

resources :shares, concerns: :deleteallable
resources :widgets, concerns: :deleteallable
```

Answer (score 2):

The right way for your case, in routes:

```
resources :shares, except: :destroy
resource :share, only: :destroy
```

Please, pay attention, that I wrote word **resource** for destroy action

Then redefine "destroy" in shares_controller:

```
  def destroy
    respond_to do |format|
      if Share.destroy_all
        format.html { redirect_to root_path, notice: 'Share collection successfully deleted' }
      else
        format.html { redirect_to root_path, notice: 'Share collection cannot be deleted.' }
      end
    end
  end
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is the non REST way of doing it:

```
resources :shares do
    collection do
        delete :destroy_all
    end
end
```

Then in your controller you will need something like this:

```
def destroy_all
    Share.delete_all
end
```

Then this is what you want to do:

```
resources :shares do
    collection do
        delete :index
    end
end
```

Then in your controller you will need something like this:

```
def index
   if request.method == delete #delete might need to be a string here, I don't know
    Share.delete_all
   else
     @shares = Share.all    
   end 
end
```

Answer (score 1):

There's a slightly simpler syntax for this that works in Rails 4.2 at least:

```
resources :shares do
  delete on: :collection, action: :destroy_all
end
```

Answer (score 0):

```
resources :shares do
    collection do
        delete '/', :to => :delete_all
    end
end
```